# Writing SQL equivalent of NSPredicate - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to write an `NSPredicate`, to select all instances; For example something similar to the following `SQL`;

> select * from person

I need to write a similar statement using `NSPredicate` (using `nspredicate` statements, and not with `SQL` statements).

```
  NSArray *allRecords= [self.records filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"HOW TO WRITE THIS"]];
```

Finally, according to the above example `allRecords` should be equal to or have the same records as `self.records`. (like we are selecting all the records from `self.records` and assigning it to `allRecords`)

Answer (score 4):

simply:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
```

If this is out of academic interest, I understand the question, but for practical purposes there are faster and cleaner ways to do what you want.

Comment: like what, can you point me a tutorial or sample code if possible

Comment: If you want an array with the contents of another array, you could do: `NSArray *secondArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:firstArray];`